# Method to get a larger version of the front face texture of my Minecraft character

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I wanted to download a picture of the player's head (of the front) like shown in the picture below:

[image: Front face texture]

But the problem is that every site I have found does not support pictures larger than 600 x 600 pixels.

I want to download it in a size of over 600 x 600 (e.g. 1000 x 1000, 800 x 800).

Sites that I found but failed me:

- [https://minecraftskinstealer.com/avatars/skin/[yourmcign]](https://minecraftskinstealer.com/avatars/skin/%5Byourmcign%5D)
  (Can't customize size)
- https://skinmc.net/en/avatars
  (Can't customize size)
- [https://mc-heads.net/avatar/Identifier/[Size]/[yourmcign]](https://mc-heads.net/avatar/Identifier/%5BSize%5D/%5Byourmcign%5D)
  (You can specify the size, but it will no longer stretch beyond 600)
- [https://minepic.org/avatar/[yourmcign]/[Size]](https://minepic.org/avatar/%5Byourmcign%5D/%5BSize%5D)
  (You can specify the size, but the size is not set after 512)

Does anyone know of an alternative method to enlarge the attached picture?

Comment: Why dont you download it and resize it yourself? there are plenty of options to do so

Comment: I don't know if it's true so take this with a grains of salt: Perhaps, the image itself isn't intended to be displayed above 600*600, so there is no file that's above 600*600. If that's the case, you could just download the maximum size available and upscale it by some tools, such as [waifu2x](https://github.com/nagadomi/waifu2x). (disclaimer: I don't own or getting paid by waifu2x's author, it's just recommendation)

Answer (score 1):

[Waifu2x](http://waifu2x.udp.jp/) can solve this problem!
It extended my picture to double size without losing qualities!

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

You can increase the size without loss of quality with most image editing software by using the Nearest Neighbour resampling option, for example in Photoshop:

[image: Photoshop Image Size menu and its options]

Here is a 2k PNG (which, because of PNG compression algorithm and the preserved hard edges, is a measly 17.1 kB):

[image: 2k .png version of the OP's original small image]

In the free image software [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/), you can go to Image → Scale (or Tools → Transform Tools → Scale), and select `None` as the Interpolation Quality:

[image: GIMP Scale menu]
<sup>Cropped detail of image from [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/125832/129895)</sup>